# Error while installing cgkit from source

Tags: python, c++, macos, cgkit

I'm trying to install library for cgkit from source on MacOS. For that I'm running command

```
python setup.py install
```

adn get this error:

```
supportlib/include/slot.h:549:5: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous
  (with operand types 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const
  boost::python::api::object')
```

How can I resolve it? Or I can resolve it only removing file slot.h and install library without it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It seems, that problem was in MacOS Command Line Tools version. I setting vagrant with Ubuntu and successfully builded library.